# Could not find add method: AddIndex (type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration) Sitecore 10.1

Tags: configuration

Just loaded Sitecore 10.1 locally, and was successful bringing up the generic Sitecore Site. Then I published my Website which is our live production site to come up, pointed my connectionStrings to my DEV environment, but this error message is now coming up, not sure where to look:

```
Could not find add method: AddIndex (type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration)
```

Comment: Did you configure your Solr server in PRD environment?

Comment: yes, and locally

Comment: OK by default Sitecore 10.1 is using Solr search as default of search engine, you need to make sure that your local solr must be published to the internet. Try to host solr somewhere and update solr connection string correctly in ConnectionString.config 

check more for detail here: https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/configure-the-solr-search-provider.html

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will review and make certain that everything is correct

Comment: Would also suggest to verify setting value for name="solr.search" in Connection String It should also point to target environment.
Please also make sure solr instance accessible from the machine where setup has been done.